# how to write below jquery code in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a requirement to make `select/deselect all checkbox` in a table using `angularjs`. I googled it but in all solutions they are using `array and ng-repeat` in angularjs. I cant use those solution bcz i am retrieving records from database and printing in a table with checkbox on each row.

I got a solution in jquery but i dont know to convert it to angularjs.
Below is the html table with jsp.

```
        <thead>
            <tr class="active">
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall">Select_All</th>
                <th>Product</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody>            
            <%    ParametersIterator it=res.getIterator();
                  String prod="";
                  int i=0;                                                                           
                  while(it.hasNext())
                  {
                   Parameters p=it.next();
                    prod=p.get("product");
                    String id=p.get("id");
             %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="<%=id%>">
                </td>
                <td><%=prod%></td>
            </tr>
            <%}%>
        </tbody>
```

below is the Jquery code

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){

// add multiple select / deselect functionality
$("#selectall").click(function () {
      $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// and viceversa
$(".case").click(function(){

    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");alert("t");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");alert("f");
    }

 });
});
</script>
```

Pls help me in converting to angularjs

Comment: "I cant use those solution bcz i am retrieving records from database and printing in a table with checkbox on each row" --> This should not prevent you from using `ng-repeat`, and it's the most sensible solution anyway. Why do you think you can't use it?

Comment: ng-repeat receives values from array defined in script. My requirement is i'm retrieving values from database.

Comment: You can load values from a database and create the table based on the DB values; you don't need to define the values in the script beforehand. Check the example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunker demonstrating a table with checkboxes, populated with data loaded from a 'server/database', with buttons to select/deselect all checkboxes. There's really no reason not to use ng-repeat with this.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
    <td>{{row.key}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.value"></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
<button ng-click="applyValues(true)">Select all</button>
<button ng-click="applyValues(false)">Unselect all</button>
```

JS:

```
$http.get('data.json')
  .then(function(res) {
    $scope.data = res.data;
  })

$scope.applyValues = function(val) {
  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(row) {
    row.value = val;
  })
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/oaDnx1kM2Zl6mtZG5Eis?p=preview

Version with a single 'Toggle all' button:

https://plnkr.co/edit/jsQuACzGSlPBok1LEPLF?p=preview

Comment: Instead of two buttons, can u help me how to make it one toggle button

Comment: Yeah, added a second solution with a "Toggle all" button @ShashankG

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your data via `$http.get('data.json')` as Fissio suggested, that's definitely the way to go. However, if you need to render the page on the server, it can still be done.

Here is a [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/dLoILaj55fioINvbBb4D?p=preview) without ng-repeat.

Comment: In your plunker example, initially select all checkbox will be checked. Can you help me make it not checked at the beginning

Comment: My mistake, I fixed my plunker by removing `refreshAllCheckbox();` initialization call (script.js line 6).